# Simple division and some radicals

Tags: radicals

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to evaluate this problem:

$$\dfrac{7}{\frac{7\sqrt{85}}{85}}$$

Everything I've found says that the answer is just $1\sqrt{85}$, but I have no idea how to get there.  The best thing I can figure out how to do is to cut it down to 
$$7 \cdot \frac{85}{7\sqrt{85}}$$

Can anyone help me with this?  Thank you!

Comment: can you please use $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Please parenthesize the expression so that it can be parsed without ambiguity.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

$7 \div {\frac{7\sqrt{85}}{85}}=7 * \frac{85}{7\sqrt{85}}=\frac{85}{\sqrt{85}}=\sqrt{85}$

Basically this is just a game of cancelling from numerator and denominator.

Comment: For the OP's benefit: $\dfrac a{\sqrt a}=\sqrt a$ for all $a$. This can be shown by rationalizing the denominator, or by taking the equation $a=\sqrt a\sqrt a$ and dividing both sides by $\sqrt a$.